# Setting up External Storage for Micro Server

Tags: ubuntu, external-hard-drive, software-raid, home-server, media-server

Need advice on a relatively cheap and stable way to set up external drives with an Optiplex micro. I upgraded my old homelab server (i5 with ZFS RAID 1 over SATA) to an Optiplex 5060 micro. Optiplex specs:

- i5 8500T
- 16GB RAM
- 2 x 2TB WD Red (not connected)

I am running Proxmox with an Ubuntu VM and Docker containers for Jellyfin, a VPN and qBittorrent. I've done some research on external harddrive enclosures and I've seen mixed opinions. My main concern is the stability of USB with a software RAID. An alternative could be using an eSATA expansion card, but it would be annoying to route it out of the Optiplex. My main questions/concerns:

- Is USB 3 stable enough for ZFS software RAID1?
- Is eSATA a better alternative?
- Is there another alternative I should look into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with a QNAP TR-002 DAS for external storage. The two disks are displayed individually in Proxmox. I did not use ZFS and instead have one drive as a backup in Proxmox and another passed through to the VM. General performance is acceptable with no differences compared to SATA. Only potential issue is that the disks run 24/7. The TR-002 will shutdown when the server is shutdown and will startup along with the server.